# org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone prints Timezone on error console

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I'm using jadira's usertype for persisting joda datetimes with hibernate 4. I need to persist the timezone as well, and therefore use org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone. When I save my datetimes, PersistentDateTimeWithZone prints the name of the timezone, for example "Europe/Berlin{+01:00}" on the error console. Since I have to persist thousands of datetimes, this is quite time consuming.

Do I have to provide the timezone in a different way?

I'm using jadira usertype 3.0.0.GA.

Thanks in advance
Christian

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to Jadira Usertype 3.1.0.GA (just released).

Disclaimer: I maintain Jadira Usertype.